# Tinc doesn't create basic config files

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora

This was done on my fedora machine (fedora release 32) and tinc-1.0.36-1.fc32.x86_64

I never really used tinc before but I need something plain and straight to the point. so I installed tinc using `sudo dnf install tinc` and just started looking around and reading the manual.

The manual said that it should have some config files, `tinc.conf`, `tinc-up`, and `tinc-down` and I haven't found any of them.

Is it expected from me to create them,or is it a bug that is so normal that people just make them?

Answer (score 0):

#### the manual said that it should have some config files, exactly `tinc.conf`, ...

In this example, we will create a virtual private network vpnname between two hosts alpha and beta, where the former is the entry point for the latter, so that beta tries to connect to alpha on startup.

> For each virtual private network you have to create a separate
> directory `/etc/tinc/network`.
>
> You can also start by copying the sample configuration
>
> ```
> # cp -r /usr/share/tinc/examples/* /etc/tinc/vpnname
> ```

So look in `/usr/share/tinc/examples`.

There are also many configuration examples at [Example setups](https://tinc-vpn.org/examples/).

Source: [Tinc - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tinc)